# Winstonjs does not log any exceptions?

Tags: node.js, koa, winston

I am using Winston to log information in my Koajs application. I have tried to make the default logger to log unhandled exceptions by following the documentation [here](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#exceptions):

But for some reason unhandled exceptions are being logged only if they are thrown from my index.js file. Throwing an exception from one of the routes does not result in winston logging the exception?

Edit:

Here is the code:

```
let winston = require('winston');

let cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
let winstonCassandra = require('../lib/winston_cassandra/index');
let config = require("../config/config");

let authProvider = new cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider(config.cassandra.username, config.cassandra.password);

let defaultLoggerOptions = {
  table: "logs",
  level: "debug",
  consistency: cassandra.types.consistencies.one,
  contactPoints: config.cassandra.contactPoints,
  keyspace: config.cassandra.keyspace,
  authProvider: authProvider,
  name: "cassandraDefaultLog"
};

let errorLoggerOptions = {
  table: "log_exceptions",
  level: "error",
  consistency: cassandra.types.consistencies.one,
  contactPoints: config.cassandra.contactPoints,
  keyspace: config.cassandra.keyspace,
  authProvider: authProvider,
  handleExceptions: true,
  name: "cassandraErrorLog"
};

winston.add(winstonCassandra, defaultLoggerOptions);
winston.add(winstonCassandra, errorLoggerOptions);

if(config.env != 'development')
{
  winston.remove(winston.transports.Console);
}
```

Comment: Please share you logger code so we can try to help you

Comment: I have edited the question to include the code.

Comment: Are other things logged from the routes? or is all logging failed there

Comment: Everything is logged ok from anywhere in the routes except exceptions are not logged. The most interesting thing is that when I throw an error in index.js it is being picked up and logged by the logger. But not if I throw the error anywhere else in the routes for example. If I throw the error anywhere else in the code it appears in the console but is not picked by the logger.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I didn't encounter this kind of behavior so let's try to triangulate the problem:
1. Please replace the logger with the regular console or file logger do The exceptions get caught there? if so then this perhaps has something to do with the winstonCassandra plugin. 
2. Please explain what do you mean by "routes" is this an express app? something similar ? what router are you using?

Comment: Another possibility is that you are actually handling those exceptions somewhere in the route (for example if you have a ```.catch()```clause in the end of a promise chain, or a promise chain that does not specifically handle failure and doesn't end with a ```.done()``` Or the framework you are using (if not vanilla express) might be using some error handling middleware already.  It should be noted that the ```handleExceptions``` property is for **unhandled exceptions**. Handled exceptions don't get logged there by default.

Comment: @alonisser We are using the `winston`logger inside a `Koajs` app. The `winstonCassandra ` plugin works fine. After some debugging we found out that if we throw an error inside the `index.js` file (where we initialize our app) the error propagates to the `module.js` file and is not handled. This is why `winston` is working. If the error is thrown inside a route, it is handled inside the `Koajs` framework. We can catch it with a `try - catch` block but it is not `unhandled` and `winston` does not work. I don't think that there is a work around where we can use the `handleExceptions` property.

Comment: @IvanStoyanov sure, that is what I meant.. ```handleExceptions``` is for unhandled exceptions. if exceptions in routes are handled they are not unHandledExceptions by definition. don't you use the builtin koajs way to handle error (and error login)? they have an example:
``` app.on('error', function(err){
  log.error('server error', err); //Here yoiu should log with winston..
});```